# React-admin + api-platform - Content-Range

Tags: symfony, react-admin, api-platform.com

I have 2 applications, both run on the docker. First backend (symfony 5 + api platform) on port 8080, second frontend(react + react-admin) on port 3000.

I can see the table to items, but when I try to load items from backend, I see all time the same bug:

```
index.js:1 Error: The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. The simple REST data provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?
```

frontend:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Admin dataProvider={simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:8080/api')}>
        <Resource name="pharmacies" list={PharmacyList} edit={PharmacyEdit} create={PharmacyCreate} icon={PharmacyIcon}/>
    </Admin>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I've had a problem with CORS, so I reconfigured the nelmio_cors.yaml:

```
  defaults:
    allow_credentials: false
    allow_origin: [ ]
    allow_headers: [ ]
    allow_methods: [ ]
    expose_headers: [ 'Content-Range' ]
    max_age: 0
    hosts: [ ]
    origin_regex: false
    forced_allow_origin_value: ~
  paths:
    '^/api/':
      allow_origin: [ '*' ]
      allow_headers: [ '*' ]
      allow_methods: [ 'POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE' ]
      max_age: 3600
    '^/':
      origin_regex: true
      allow_origin: [ '^http://localhost:[0-9]+' ]
      allow_headers: [ '*' ]
      allow_methods: [ 'POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE' ]
      max_age: 3600
      hosts: [ '^api\.' ]
```

The response header:

```
Server: nginx/1.19.5
Content-Type: application/ld+json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.13
Vary: Accept
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: deny
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Sun, 21 Feb 2021 13:00:55 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-range
Link: <http://localhost:8080/api/docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation"
ETag: "0eeb89535116e4257a2152e977020a7a"
X-Debug-Token: 0f9844
X-Debug-Token-Link: http://localhost:8080/_profiler/0f9844
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

Where is my mistake? What am I doing wrong? It's a problem with frontend app, symfony config(nelmo) or http server (nginx)? I read a lot of posts on SOF/github and other blogs. Nothing can help.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html - I tried to disable it in cors headers and force this header on nelmo/api-platform. It `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-range` doesn't help.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you managed to figure this out?